# For /F: Spaces in both filename and parameter

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-line-arguments

In a batch file I want to set a variable to the one-line output of a program - a task explained in multiple questions and internet ressources.

In my specific task I want to execute the command

```
"D:\__My Program\___My Program\Folder1\Folder2\..\..\FileVersion\FileVersion\bin\Release\FileVersion.exe" /n "D:\__My Program\___My Program\Folder1\Folder2\bin\Deploy\My Program.exe"
```

As you can see, the path for the program I want to execute, `FileVersion.exe` contains spaces, and the second parameter handed to `FileVersion.exe` contains a full path with spaces as well.

When I call the above command either directly at the command line or by using `CALL` in the batch file it correctly executes the program prints out the expected output.

Now, to capture the output of executing the program I use the follow batch command

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i IN (`"D:\__My Program\___My Program\Folder1\Folder2\..\..\FileVersion\FileVersion\bin\Release\FileVersion.exe" /n "D:\__My Program\___My Program\Folder1\Folder2\bin\Deploy\My Program.exe"`) DO (
    echo %%i
)
```

The [FOR documentation](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) says

```
usebackq     Use the alternate quoting style:                        
           - Use double quotes for long file names in "filenameset".
           - Use single quotes for 'Text string to process'
           - Use back quotes for `command to process`
```

I think I did this correctly by using back quotes around the command, and using quotes around the filenames.

However, the call fails with the message (translated from German)

```
The command "D:\My" is either incorrect or couldn't be found.
```

I think this points to a problem with escaping the spaces.

The weird part: If I either replace the path of the exe to call, or the parameter with a path *sans* spaces, it works. So both

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i IN (`FileVersion.exe /n "D:\__My Program\___My Program\Folder1\Folder2\bin\Deploy\My Program.exe"`) DO (
    echo %%i
)
```

and

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i IN (`"D:\__My Program\___My Program\Folder1\Folder2\..\..\FileVersion\FileVersion\bin\Release\FileVersion.exe" /n Test.exe`) DO (
    echo %%i
)
```

work.

**Why don't two quote-escaped strings work in the same command and how can I fix it?**

Comment: I'm not sure that I see the purpose of using back quotes!

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22636308/2861476) solves your problem.

Comment: Compo: This doesn't make a difference.
@MCND Your's does. I was sure there had to be a resource that answered it but I didn't find it while sifting through the examples. Thanks. I'll mark it as duplicate.

Comment: The example seems a little bit more complicated that this question (because of the _caret_ char and also the redirector operator). Translated to what we have here: `for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('""D:\__My Program\___My Program\Folder1\Folder2\..\..\FileVersion\FileVersion\bin\Release\FileVersion.exe" /n "D:\__My Program\___My Program\Folder1\Folder2\bin\Deploy\My Program.exe""') DO (`... .

Comment: @CristiFati Yes putting the double-quotes around the whole thing, while still adding quotes around each path is the solution I used as well. It was the first example in the accepted answer of the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `usebackq` and first resolve the complex path:

```
@Echo off
Pushd "D:\__My Program\___My Program\Folder1\Folder2\..\..\FileVersion\FileVersion\bin\Release"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (
  ' FileVersion.exe /n "D:\__My Program\___My Program\Folder1\Folder2\bin\Deploy\My Program.exe" '
) DO echo %%i
PopD
```